# How to create .sub (vobsub sutitle sub/idx) file from bitmap files

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mpeg, subtitle, mpeg-2

I have some bitmap files (jpeg, png, ...) and I want to write a C++ program that joins those bitmap files to pes stream (mpeg-2 format), then create a sub file (.sub/.idx: vobsub subtitle files).

Can you give me some hint?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Can't you just call ffmpeg ?

First gogle result : http://tooloftrade.blogspot.fr/2011/10/merging-images-into-movie-using-ffmpeg.html